# How to make an AST for variable declarations and use symbol table?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I have this programming language:

```
BEGIN CODE 
    INT a, b, d = 10, c = 10
    DISPLAY: d + c
END CODE
```

I made the rules like this for the parser and wanted to create an AST for this.

```
variable_declaration → TYPE IDENTIFIER variable_declarationprime
                     | TYPE assignment
variable_declarationprime → ',' IDENTIFIER variable_declarationprime
                          | ',' assignment variable_declarationprime
                          | ε
assignment → IDENTIFIER '=' expression
expression → arithmetic_expression
           | boolean_expression
```

But I'm confused how does AST make a tree for variable declarations considering this 1 and 2, and many resources gives symbol table construction.

1.

```
INT a = 10
```

2. 

```
INT b
```

Comment: `INT a = 10` is a `TYPE` followed by an `assignment` whereas `INT b` is a `TYPE` followed by an `IDENTIFIER` and an `ε`

Comment: how do you call that in AST if INT a, b, c = 10? VariableDeclarations AST type?